# Creating Applicative instance of a stateful signal type with Elerea

Tags: haskell, frp, elerea

I am hacking around in [Helm](https://github.com/switchface/helm) trying to create a stateful signal type that will carry additional info on whether the value has changed since the last sampling. I have managed to make the new signal type an instance of `Functor` but I am struggling to define the `<*>` function of `Applicative` which would allow me to lift multiple signals into one function.

The only signal I have defined so far is the `constant` signal that would have a `Changed x` on the initial sampling and an `Unchanged x` thereafter. Additional signals would be more complex and use [`Elerea.stateful`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/elerea-2.7.0.2/docs/FRP-Elerea-Simple.html#v:stateful) to determine whether the value has changed.

`lift2` wouldn't work in the code below because `<*>` hasn't been defined yet.

```
import qualified FRP.Elerea.Simple as Elerea
import Control.Applicative

data Event a = Changed a | Unchanged a

instance Functor Event where
    fmap f (Changed a)   = Changed (f a)
    fmap f (Unchanged a) = Unchanged (f a)

instance Applicative Event where
    pure = Unchanged
    (Changed   f) <*> (Changed   x) = Changed (f x)
    (Changed   f) <*> (Unchanged x) = Changed (f x)
    (Unchanged f) <*> (Changed   x) = Changed (f x)
    (Unchanged f) <*> (Unchanged x) = Unchanged (f x)

data Signal a = Signal (Elerea.SignalGen (Elerea.Signal (Event a)))

instance Functor Signal where
    fmap f (Signal x) = Signal ((fmap . fmap . fmap) f x)

instance Applicative Signal where
    pure = Signal . pure . pure . pure
    --(<*>) = ??

{-| Creates a signal that never changes. -}
constant :: a -> Signal a
constant x = Signal $ Elerea.stateful (Changed x) (\_ -> Unchanged x)

lift :: (a -> b) -> Signal a -> Signal b
lift = fmap

lift2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> Signal a -> Signal b -> Signal c
lift2 f a b = fmap f a <*> b
```

Full code that I am working with currently is on [Github](https://github.com/kasbah/helm/blob/a57d6a9cc06563f022c93b21e09162a50b6edcd6/src/FRP/Helm/Utilities.hs).

Comment: Why does `Signal` incorporate `SignalGen`?

Comment: So Elerea defines `Elerea.Signal` and `Elerea.SignalGen`. Signals in Elerea are eventless and just constant streams of values. I am trying to define a new Signal type, closer to the [Elm](http://elm-lang.org) idea of Signals that can be used to determine if the main Element needs re-calculating and re-rendering (when the values have changed since the last sampling).

Comment: Also see this [Helm issue](https://github.com/switchface/helm/issues/64) (the bounty was created by me).

Comment: Maybe more clear: `Elerea.stateful` returns a `Elerea.SignalGen (Elerea.Signal a)` and I am trying to wrap that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `pure . pure . pure` is:

```
(Applicative f, Applicative f1, Applicative f2) => a -> f (f1 (f2 a))
```

So you just want to lift the `<*>` through two additional applicative layers. You need a function with the signature:

```
(Applicative f, Applicative f1, Applicative f2) => f (f1 (f2 (a -> b))) -> f (f1 (f2 a)) -> f (f1 (f2 b))
```

This function can be made by applying `liftA2` twice, so please try this:

```
(Signal f) <*> (Signal x) = Signal $ (liftA2 (liftA2 (<*>))) f x
```

Comment: That works! Thank you very much for the answer and explaining your thought process in getting there. Note to self: always look at the types.